# add date(created_at) to pervious data on postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, date

I have a SQL database that records some data on 5 days of the week(Monday to Friday), I have a row that set time of day that data is created like this `14:25:16` but I didn't add a column that record the date.( Actually, I download data from somewhere that it has time of day but not the date)
Is there any hidden data on PostgreSQL that saves something like created_at or is there any robust algorithm to add date to my database? I want to create a time series of my data and without date my data is useless.

I tried to do something with python and pandas data frame to construct a mechanism that finds out when hour is increasing:

`hour
23
23--> this is the row that day will change after
00
00`

but I found that my data has some caveat because there were days that no news data was downloaded.

Comment: producing artificial date fro time is easy, but I don't understand how you can do it with gaps - how would you know the length of a gap?.. also Postgres does not track the timestamps of data midification or so (if that what you meant)

Comment: that my question too? I download some currency and gold price data, some of them update more frequency(every minute) and some of them update with less frequency(twice per week) so its hard for me to manipulate the gap.
And yes tracking timestamps is exactly what I want.

Comment: whats your idea about producing artificial date?

Answer (score 0):

mocking up the artificial timestamp is yeasy with some logic and window functions, eg:

```
with c(i,t) as (values(1,'11:0:00'::time),(2,'23:00'),(3,'02:00'),(4,'01:00'),(5,'23:00'),(6,'01:00'),(7,'02:00'))
, d(s) as (values('1980.09.19'::timestamp))
, n as (select *,case when lag(t) over(order by i) > t then i else 0 end c from c)
, f as (select *,s+ concat( (dense_rank() over (order by c nulls first)-1)::text ,' days')::interval art from n join d on true)
select i,t, case when art = s then coalesce(lag(art) over (order by i),s) else art end cs 
from f order by i;
 i |    t     |         cs
---+----------+---------------------
 1 | 11:00:00 | 1980-09-19 00:00:00
 2 | 23:00:00 | 1980-09-19 00:00:00
 3 | 02:00:00 | 1980-09-20 00:00:00
 4 | 01:00:00 | 1980-09-21 00:00:00
 5 | 23:00:00 | 1980-09-21 00:00:00
 6 | 01:00:00 | 1980-09-22 00:00:00
 7 | 02:00:00 | 1980-09-22 00:00:00
(7 rows)
```

but you can't guess the size of the gap. so If you have no info on it - you can't build it...